# Can't use Meteor images that are in the folder public

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm searching since a little time now how to use my images that are in the folder /public/images/myImg.png

There is my Javascript code (I have tried without '..' with '/public...'):
/imports/ui/body.html

```
<div id="logoG">
   <img src= "../public/images/logo.png"/>
</div>
```

And that's the structure of my project:
[image]

[EDIT] The result is that: [image]

Comment: try `../../public/images/logo.png`

Comment: It's not the solution, if u need the solution look the one of @ovidiuDolha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the 'public' prefix

```
<img src= "/images/logo.png"/>
```

Comment: You're the hero ! Thank you ! (I'll put your answer as solution but I need to wait 12minutes idk why)